# WebApi unable to return to HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, google-api-dotnet-client

It gets stuck after the end curly-brace when I am trying to call `GetAllFiles()` from `HttpClient` (MVC application).  I can see the data in debug mode, but when reaching then ending brace it gets stuck.

When I call the same WebApi method from postman, I can easily get the data.

```
public class FileToDriveController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllFiles()
    {
        //Gets credentials 
        GoogleUtility googleUtility = new GoogleUtility();
        UserCredential credential = googleUtility.GetCredential();

        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "DriveApiFileUpload"
        });

        var listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.MaxResults = 10;

        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Items;

        if(files!=null)
        {
            return Ok(files); //i can see files here in debug mode
        }

        return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

This is the HttpClient's call to the api

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> getAllFiles()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:16184/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync("api/FileToDrive/GetAllFiles");

        if (message.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return message;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a tricky one that is caused by a deadlock when making async calls from within a controller. See this excellent explanation: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

> The top-level method calls GetJsonAsync (within the UI/ASP.NET context).
>   GetJsonAsync starts the REST request by calling HttpClient.GetStringAsync (still within the context).
>   GetStringAsync returns an uncompleted Task, indicating the REST request is not complete.
>   GetJsonAsync awaits the Task returned by GetStringAsync. The context is captured and will be used to continue running the GetJsonAsync method later. GetJsonAsync returns an uncompleted Task, indicating that the GetJsonAsync method is not complete.
>   The top-level method synchronously blocks on the Task returned by GetJsonAsync. This blocks the context thread.
>   … Eventually, the REST request will complete. This completes the Task that was returned by GetStringAsync.
>   The continuation for GetJsonAsync is now ready to run, and it waits for the context to be available so it can execute in the context.
>   Deadlock. The top-level method is blocking the context thread, waiting for GetJsonAsync to complete, and GetJsonAsync is waiting for the context to be free so it can complete.

To solve your issue (again, taken from the blog post):

> In your “library” async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever possible.
>   Don’t block on Tasks; use async all the way down.

Comment: Thank you Eran. This really helped me a lot. The link to the blog helped me a lot.

Comment: I got a major headache trying to figure this out when I first encountered it, glad I could help!